# How to prevent INPAINTING blocks and improve coloring

Tags: python, opencv, text, computer-vision

I wanted to Remove all the texts USING INPAINTING from this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxOdS.jpg). I had been trying various methods, and eventually found that I can get the results through OCR and then using thresholding MASK THE IMAGE.

```
processedImage = preprocess(partOFimg) 
mask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255
for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 0, -1)
img = cv2.inpaint(img,mask,7,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

Preprocess operations:

```
  ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 3))
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations = 1)
edged = cv2.Canny(dilation, 50, 100)
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
mask =

np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255
```

When I run the above code, I here am the OUTPUT Image [OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Q2k.png). As we can see, it is making some BLOCKS OF DIFFERENT COLOR over the IMAGE, I want to prevent that, How do I achieve this? I see that mask images are not formed well many times, and in cases when the text is white the PREPROCESSING doesn't occur properly.
How do I prevent these BLOCKS of other colours to FORM on the IMAGE?

Grayed Sub Image [GRAYED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4AMq.png)

Threshold Sub IMG part: [Thresholded Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLEzE.png)

Masked Image [Masked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E22hL.png)

EDIT 1:

[image: NEW RESULT]
I've managed to get this new better result by noticing that my threshold is the best mask I can get. After doing this I performed the masking process 3 different times with variable masks and inversions. I did the inpainting algorithm 3 times, it basically the other times inverse the mask, because in some cases required mask is the inversed mask. Still I think it needs improvement, If I chose a different image the results are not so good.

Comment: Inpaint requires a binary mask. I do not not see that as one of your output images. Do you have that?  Your blocks are coming from the dilation and canny edge processing, I believe. You should display results from each step to find where that happens. Looks like that may be from getting each word rather than each letter and not the contour of each word. Your structuring element is a wide horizontal rectangle. That will give a rectangular region as output. Perhaps you should find the green region, then threshold on the white letters inside the green.

Comment: The binary mask image is in the last link

Comment: In your case, the thresholded image is good at capturing the text. For inpainting, you need a mask that exactly covers or slightly exceeds the object that you want to remove. First, reverse the thresholded image such that the mask for the text becomes white in color and the rest is black. That is required for opencv (https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html). Try this image itself as the mask. In case you need to make the mask slightly bigger, dilate the white mask using a small square structuring element.

Comment: Yes, So instead of reversing I noticed that my threshold can be the required mask, So I am using that as my mask. But yes the size is a concern, can you tell me what you mean by SMALL SQUARE STRUCTURING ELEMENT please?

Comment: Also one more thing that I noticed, when my text is in 'white' then sometimes INPAINTING doesn't works and I have to INVERT THE MASK. I'm thinking to use the inpainting algorithm for 2 times in case such happenings arise, do you have any idea of a better way?

Comment: The OpenCV inpainting technique is not good at removing block regions. You need a different technique such as exemplar method (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/criminisi_tip2004.pdf). For your image, you should try to get a mask of the exact letter characters (slightly larger) rather than rectangular blocks of words.

Comment: I'd be grateful to know how can I programmatically increase the masks letter size

Comment: Maybe, you should understand better how image dilation works. The Wikipedia page is good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology). There they show dilation by a small 3X3 structuring element. Maybe, you need 5X5 or 7X7 etc. For e.g., `rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations = 1)`. Try and see. Remember, the mask over the text is white and the rest is black. The color of the objects covered by the mask will not influence the result. Unless a small bit of the object is not covered.

Comment: It is true that Bertalmio et al's inpainting method is better suited for inpainting small crack like regions. However, if the background is relatively smooth (like the green board in this case), larger foreground objects (like the text) can be removed. For e.g., this page shows good results with larger objects: https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/18/image-inpainting-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: Yes indeed, but for me I want it to work with small things - words

Comment: Yes so  I noticed at night that, I had been improperly doing the masks so I improved it and also added the current result

Comment: I recently saw some more modern inpainting algorithms implemented in OpenCV. the TELEA/NS stuff is old and not even trying to replicate texture/content. the new stuff can do that because it's DNN-based, afaics.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, I've seen them but basically I also want to improve my auto masking of image

Comment: I want that for whatever color the text be masks should be proper :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python/OpenCV inpaint methods, generally, are not appropriate to your type of image. They work best on thin (scratch-like) regions, not large blocks. You really need an exemplar type method such as https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/criminisi_tip2004.pdf. But OpenCV does not have that.

However, the OpenCV methods do work here, I suspect, because you are filling with constant colors (green) and not texture. So you are best to try to get the mask of just the letters (characters), not rectangular blocks for the words.  So, to show you what I mean, here is my Python/OpenCV approach.

Input:

[image]

- Read the input
- Threshold on the green sign
- Apply morphology to close it up and keep as mask1
- Apply the mask to the image to blacken out the outside of the sign
- Threshold on the white in this new image and keep as mask2
- Apply morphology dilate to enlarge it slightly and save as mask3
- Do the inpaint
- Save the results

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
img = cv2.imread('airport_sign.jpg')

# threshold on green sign
lower = (30,80,0)
upper = (70,120,20)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# apply morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (135,135))
mask1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply mask to img
img2 = img.copy()
img2[mask1==0] = (0,0,0)

# threshold on white
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#mask2 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
lower = (120,120,120)
upper = (255,255,255)
mask2 = cv2.inRange(img2, lower, upper)

# apply morphology dilate
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
mask3 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask2, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)


# do inpainting
result1 = cv2.inpaint(img,mask3,11,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
result2 = cv2.inpaint(img,mask3,11,cv2.INPAINT_NS)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('airport_sign_mask.png', mask3)
cv2.imwrite('airport_sign_inpainted1.png', result1)
cv2.imwrite('airport_sign_inpainted2.png', result1)

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask1',mask1)
cv2.imshow('img2',img2)
cv2.imshow('mask2',mask2)
cv2.imshow('mask3',mask3)
cv2.imshow('result1',result1)
cv2.imshow('result2',result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask 3:

[image]

Inpaint 1 (Telea):

[image]

Inpaint 2 (NS):

[image]

Comment: In these lines, `result1 = cv2.inpaint(img,thresh,11,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
result2 = cv2.inpaint(img,thresh,11,cv2.INPAINT_NS)`, shouldn't the mask over the text (`mask3`) be passed, instead of `thresh`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I caught that already and fixed my answer. It was a cut and paste error from a previous script that I forgot to change. So my answer is now quite a bit different that before. But thanks for notifying me. You are correct and have a sharp eye.

Comment: Amazing but I notice that the bottom part of the text is not removed. You see in the bottom, the white colored text it is still there

Comment: In order to solve this I had been thinking of applying mask and inpainting 2-3 times with variable masks

Comment: I want my code to work for both cases, in case of DARK text as well as WHITE, I have thought the above view yet.

Comment: I think  if there could be a way of detecting if the text is lighter than the background then you need to invert the threshold and if not then do not invert. Any idea how can I generalize this?