# Issue while removing text and inpainting the image back for some of the images its creating blurriness in the background

Tags: python, opencv, keras, ocr

I am removing text from image using keras ocr then writing it back with cv2.inpaint but creating blurriness in the background

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please take the [tour], then review [ask] and [mre] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790198/how-to-prevent-inpainting-blocks-and-improve-coloring/73791744#73791744